# Filling up an empty cell with adjacent cell's value

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a simple script which can turn this

[image: screen1]

**into this**

[image: screen2]

As you can see I have manually copied and pasted those empty cells in E column with the corresponging value from the A column: I need a script that can do this automatically.

I guess it needs building two different sets of data from two different arrays, and then comparing them, but unfortunately I don't have any idea how to perform that ..

```js
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet     = ss.getSheetByName('name');
  var lastRow   = sheet.getLastRow();
  var extension = lastRow - 1;
  
  var colA = sheet.getRange(1, 1, extension).getValues();
  var colE = sheet.getRange(1, 5, extension).getValues();
..
  }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for retrieving your expected output situation from your sample input situation. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for you answer my logic is: retrieve each index in the array colE where the value is "" (blank); then take the value of the same index from the colA. And I am still looking how to do that, thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted and the discussions have been positively advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussions.

Comment: @Tanaike I guess your answer would be much appreciated anyway, especially since the provided answer didn't lead to a resolution of the problem at the moment and the process is stuck. If you have a suggestion, a proposal, personally I would be glad to hear it. And I am sure a more comprehensive discussione could benefit the whole question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your objective is as follows:

When column `(fine)(F)`  is empty, fill it with the value of column `data(A)`.

The steps are:

1. Get the values of your data.
2. Check which rows have a length less than 5
3. Fill that one with the data from column A.

**Sample**:

###### `Code.gs`

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
function fillEmpty() {
  /* Getting the data from the sS */
  const range = sS.getRange('A2:E' + sS.getLastRow())
  const values = range.getValues()
  /* Tmp Values */
  let tempValues = []
  values.forEach((row, idx) => {
    /* Check the length of the array */
    const check = row[4]

    /* UPDATED TO CHECK ONLY IF THE `fine` exists */
    if(check){
      tempValues.push(row)
    } else {
      /* Change the color for the modified */
      sS.getRange(idx + 2, 5).setBackground('#ffee00')
      let tmpR = row
      tmpR[4] = tmpR[0]
      tempValues.push(tmpR)
    }
  })
  range.setValues(tempValues)
}
```

**From this:**

| data | evento | etichetta | dettagli | (fine) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2022 | BLA | BLE | BLI | 1/10/2022 |
| 1/15/2022 | BLA | BLE | BLI |  |
| 1/20/2022 | BLA | BLE |  |  |
| 1/25/2022 | BLA | BLE |  |  |
| 2/25/2022 | BLA | BLE | BLI | 2/25/2022 |

**To this:**

| data | evento | etichetta | dettagli | (fine) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2022 | BLA | BLE | BLI | 1/10/2022 |
| 1/15/2022 | BLA | BLE | BLI | 1/15/2022 |
| 1/20/2022 | BLA | BLE |  | 1/20/2022 |
| 1/25/2022 | BLA | BLE |  | 1/25/2022 |
| 2/25/2022 | BLA | BLE | BLI | 2/25/2022 |

##### **Documentation**

- [`setValues(Object[][])`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately this doesn't work because not all rows will always have at least 4 values (step 2 of your process): sometimes they miss both the value from column E ("fine") AND from column D ("dettagli").

Comment: I have considered that when building the script. And when I have tested it it works as expected (As I have indicated in my answer). What are you finding wrong? You can check it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XvxYw1MYyyrwUeluFZw4dHMhvwdDAEfx8EWMAt6mFUA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: thanks. I made a small clip with my issue: https://sendvid.com/u52kpbbw At first I thought it was caused by notes within some cells, but I guess it's not.

Comment: That's odd... Can you share a sanitized copy of the sheet where the issue is reproducible? Also, I have just realized that the `fill` function is not necessary, modify `let tempRow = row.fill("", len, 5)` to `let tmpRow = row`, perhaps it will solve the problem.

Comment: I modified as you suggested but nothing changed. Additionally I also noticed something new: the script is going to change also some correct date, some date that were already written within column A! Here's the link to the video https://sendvid.com/vxmig4t6 Thanks

Comment: I see, please, share a sanitized copy of the sheet. It would be make easier the debug problem, as I can reproduce it on my own sheet!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244295/discussion-between-emel-and-john-galassi).

Comment: Okey, I detect where the error is, I updated the script

Comment: I'm sorry Emel but it still doesn't work. Lets move to the chat

Comment: Is not reproducible on my side, can you share a sanitized sheet¿?

Comment: Just tested, change the line `const range = sS.getRange('A2:E' + sS.getLastColumn())` to `const range = sS.getRange('A2:E' + sS.getLastRow())`. Edited in the answer

Comment: ok thanks, It works! I would like to ask you an additional feature: how can I set a specific background color ONLY for those cells that have been filled? Thanks

Comment: Edited the script to add this feature, please provide the bounty.

Comment: The trick `sS.getRange(idx + 2, 5).setBackground('#ffee00')` see the answer

Comment: I already marked the answer correct and I thought it would provide the bounty by default: it is the first time for me and only now I understand I'll have to wait two hours to award you. But please don't doubt my good faith man. Let's try to keep this elegant here: read the message I left you in the chat instead if you have some time and you'll understand that your request was redundant.. Thanks for the additional trick anyways